# exclude google users from syncing - google GCDS

Tags: active-directory, google-workspace, data-synchronization

I have google users created under my G-suite domain (user@myDomain.com) and I want to exlude them from syncing into my microsoft AD, beacuase it shows that they will be disabled since they don't exist in my AD.

Answer (score 0):

You would create an exclusion rule, specifically a "Google domain exclusion rule": https://support.google.com/a/answer/6138405?hl=en

You would either add an exclusion for each user specifically:

```
Type: User Email Address
Match Type: Exact Match
Rule: user@domain.com
```

Or find some other property that identifies those users and use that in your rule.